# The logic of the if statement ()

Tags: javascript, function

Could you give some explanation on how is **if (checkAge(age))** is a condition?

A simple age checking function:

```
function checkAge(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return confirm('Do you have permission from your parents?');
  } 
} 

let age = prompt('How old are you?', 18);
if ( checkAge(age) ) {
  alert( 'Access granted' );
} else {
  alert( 'Access denied' );
}
```

Does that mean the function become "true" if meet either requirement (>=18 or confirmed)?

Why the if statement below can execute when I just put a true value in it? (i.e. IF(1) )

Is the ok to write `if(checkAge(age) == true)`? If not, why?

Also which part of the code called the function? the lower if statement?

Sorry as I am a beginner and just wanna get a clear vision of the logic.

Comment: *"does that mean the function become "true" if meet either requirement (>=18 or confirmed)?"* Yes (and by become, you mean *return*)

Comment: *"is the ok to write `if (checkAge(age) == true)`"* Yes, but it's redundant. `if (checkAge(age))` is enough

Comment: *"also which part of the code called the function? the lower if statement?"* Yes again

Comment: What do you mean by *"executive"*?

Comment: Thx so much sir, I just re-visit the tutorial and please ignore the "why the if statement below can executive", and by executive i mean execute, sorry abt that.

Comment: @KaneLee you can edit your question if you’d like?

Comment: Welcome!
I think Cid pretty much answered all you questions!
About "executive"/"execute" - you can edit the question and correct that.
To emphasize: when JavaScript sees a function, it executes it, and replaces it's result where it was written.  Here: inside an `if` statement.  It looks for a return value to use, and if none found, it will use `undefined`.  Kind of like in Math: evaluate expression in parentheses, replace it with its result, and re-evaluate the outer expression.

Comment: thank you guys so much.